# Selector for item NOT descended from another item

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given the HTML below, how would you select all .name(s) that are NOT descendents of .itemcontainer(s).

Something like .group .header .name:not(descended from .itemcontainer)

I know this could be done pretty easily with jQuery or by adding other classes, but any pure css solutions?  I haven't been able to find a "not descended from" selector...

```
<div class='group'>

    <!-- Any number of ancestors of any type -->

    <div class='header'>

         <!-- Any number of ancestors of any type -->

        <div class='name'>

            SELECT ME!!!

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class='body'>

        <div class='itemcontainer'>

            <div class='item1'>

                <!-- Any number of ancestors of any type -->

                <div class='header'>

                        <!-- Any number of ancestors of any type -->

                    <div class='name'>

                            DON'T SELECT ME!!!

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class='body'>

                    ...

                </div>

            </div>

                ...

        </div>

    </div>

        ...

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way to exclude such in a CSS selector; but you could define a rule for all, then undefine for the specific.

```
.group .header .name {
    background-color: green;
}
.group .itemcontainer .header .name {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

**EDIT**: Given what you're trying to achieve (taken from the comments to my answer), it makes much more sense not to do it as a pure CSS selector, but indeed with jQuery:

```
$('.group .header .name').filter(':not(.itemcontainer *)')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.click(onClick);
```

Comment: Good idea.  In this case, I'm actually trying to bind an event handler to the group names that will show/hide the body, so I would have to exclude them in jQuery.  I just handled it by adding a separate class (.group_expand) to the group names, though I would much rather have a way to just specify the groups desired =o)

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are trying to do is this:

```
.name:not(.itemcontainer .name)
```

**But this won't work** because the selector `:not()` only accepts simple selectors. In other words: I don't think that you will be able to accomplish this with the `:not()` selector, sorry.